# Lego Duplo Train Track Switcher washable? / Best way to clean them?

Tags: piece-information, trains, duplo, cleaning, disassembly

I've found some pretty old Lego Duplo train track parts, that I'm looking to sell on Ebay.

As these are pretty old and caked with dust, I wanted to used my usual method I usually use to clean all kinds of Lego parts: Put them in a duvet cover with a zipper so they don't go everywhere, and put them in the washing machine, and wash without any detergent and no spin cycle.

Afterwards I take them out of the machine (thanks to the duvet cover I can take them out just like a bag) and spread them on my terrace to leave them in the sun to dry.

As [these track switchers](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6379c01&idColor=10#T=P&C=10) have metal springs in them (at least I think so, judging based on the sound when moving the red thing) I was not sure, if they were just normal steel or stainless. Does anyone of you know about this, or know a way to open them without destroying them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.cailliau.org/Alphabetical/L/Lego/Duplo/Train/Rails/Switches/%20Switches-en.html) it is glued together and can not be opened without damaging the part

You are correct about it containing a metal spring
[image]

I would just wipe it with a slighty wet towel